# AS3 - Using same symbol different image?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, symbols

Basically I'm working on a new game and have decided to come up with the idea of having different enemies - however would I have to create multiple symbol's for these enemies or can I use that one symbol and change the image that is loaded onto it?

If yes - how would I go about doing this?

Currently the symbol is known as `Enemy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your symbol must be movie clip. In each frame there are different images and added by label. to change the enemy you can call:

```
Enemy.gotoAndStop(labels)// use Enemy.gotoAndPlay(labels) if you want the animated ones.
```

with labels is a string.